# elasticsearch: using wildcards for integer values

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to find all objects which have a year value which starts with 20... so I would like to search for 20*, where * is a wild card. 
I tries something like

```
'match_phrase_prefix': { 'year': { 'query': '20*', 'max_expansions': 50}}
```

but I guess this only works for strings. How would I do this for integers?

EDIT: I found a solution... its not pretty but it works

```
year_query = '20'
if len(str(year_query)) < 4:
    try:
        low_year, high_year = extend_year(int(year_query))
        filter_list.append({"range": {"year": {"gte": low_year, "lte": high_year}}})
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a valid input for year"
        pass
else:
    for year in year_query.split(','):
        if '-' in year:
            year_range = year.split('-')
            high_year = year_range[1].strip()
            if len(high_year) < 4:
                low_year, high_year = extend_year(high_year)
                try:
                    filter_list.append({"range" : {"year" : {"gte" : int(year_range[0].strip()),"lte" : int(high_year),"format": "yyyy"}}})
                except ValueError:
                    print "Not a valid input for year"
                    pass
            else:
                try:
                    filter_list.append({ "match": {"year": int(year.strip()) }})
                except ValueError:
                    print "Not a valid input for year"
                    pass
```

with the function

```
def extend_year(input_year):
    length = len(str(input_year))
    if length == 4:
        return input_year, 0
    elif length == 3:
        return input_year*10, int(str(input_year) + '9')
    elif length == 2:
        return input_year*100, int(str(input_year) + '99')
    elif length == 1:
        return input_year*1000, int(str(input_year) + '999')
    elif length == 0:
        return 0, 9999
    else:
        return input_year, 0
```

if anybody can come up with a better solution please let me know

Comment: If your field is a year then I assume that you want to find all years greater than 2000. So maybe you can use a range query?

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
'range': { 'year': { 'gte': 2000, 'max_expansions': 50}}
```

Comment: if somebody enters 19 I don't want it to match papers which start with 20... I implemented now a range query which is a bit convoluted... but works

Comment: It's a numerical range, so it should only match numbers larger than 2000. You could a "lt" for 2100 then. Although I'm confused as to what you really want.